# BeautifulSoup finding and replacing text causes HTML problems

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
for finding in soup.findAll(text=reg_compiled_keyword):
   if finding.parent.name == "img":
      continue

   new_text = re.sub(reg_compiled_keyword,cls.keyword_replace_tmpl.format(escaped_kw,id,escaped_kw),finding)

   finding.replaceWith(new_text)
```

For loop returns NavigableString objects, and if I use the replace function, it also replaces the text within the attributes which causes invalid HTML of course.

How can I check if the current NavigableString is within an attribute so that I can skip it ?

Comment: It is my understanding that find_all() will not give you NavigableStrings that are attribute values. Are you sure you are getting NavigableStrings that are within attribute values?

Comment: Can you post a small html sample that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Hi, I found out that the return object was indeed a Comment object, not a NavigableString. Thanks for the heads up @Ansari

Comment: Well, Comment is a subclass of NavigableString ..

Comment: I suggest checking finding.__class__.name against the name of the Comment class and skipping the substitution if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that find_all() will not give you NavigableStrings that are attribute values. Are you sure you are getting NavigableStrings that are within attribute values?

Assuming you somehow can or I'm wrong, try this to see if what you have is an attribute value.

```
finding.string in finding.parent.attrs.values()
```

(Of course, check prior to this that .parent and .parent.attrs() are valid Objects))

This will return `True` if the NavigableString `finding` is an attribute value.

If you wanted to see whether `finding` is an attribute (not an attribute value) then you would replace `values()` with `keys()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not sure whether if I should mark this as answer ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: Well, I just modified my answer to be slightly more complete. I'm glad my comment helped you troubleshoot. I did answer your main question of how to check if some string is within an attribute or attribute value, it might be useful to someone coming across this question later, and you're going to lose to 50 bounty points anyway, so I do suggest marking this as the answer :P